# Como crear columnas a partir de registros de otra tabla- laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

quería consultarles si es posible hacer lo siguiente
tengo una tabla `productos` del tipo:

```
id  producto  descripcion
1   1         clear 1
2   2         clear 2
3   3         clear 3
.   .         .
.   .         .
n   n         descripcionN
```

y necesito hacer otra tabla llamada `volinv` del tipo:

```
cod_rodal  tipo  prod1  prod 2  .... prodn
101199702  R     50     100     .... 0
101199801  C     90     10      .... 0
```

donde `prod1` sería `clear 1`, `prod2`= `clear 2` y asi hasta que `prodn` sería `descripcionN`

pasa que los datos de la tabla producto van a ir aumentando, por lo que necesito que las columnas de los productos de la tabla volinv se generen "dinámicamente"

aca mi migración de volinv

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('volinvs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('cod_rodal');
        $table->integer('edad');
        $table->string('tipo');
        $table->integer('prod1');
        $table->integer('prod2');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

como podría modificar la migración para que pueda generar las columnas "productos" que se encuentran en mi tabla productos?

Comment: No veo al momento relación de Laravel en tu pregunta, parece solo un tema de bases de datos salvo que edites y amplies contextualizando un poco más

Comment: ok gracias, ahi modifiqué

Comment: Me parece un tanto raro querer dar ese nivel de privilegios de creación de tablas columnas, considero lo tienes mal planteado pues tu base de datos ya debe tener desde el inicio la estructura completa para almacenar datos puede que algunos sean obligatorios y otros no, por eso te decía esto no tiene que ver con Laravel sino como conceptualizas tu base de datos